# Convergence of infinite series for $\sum {{a_n}} $ and $\sum {{b_n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Let $\sum {{a_n}} $ and $\sum {{b_n}}$ be two series of positive terms and suppose that the sequence {${a_n/b_n}$} converges to 0.  Prove that

a) If $\sum {a_n}$ diverges to + $\infty $ then $\sum {b_n}$ diverges to +$\infty$

b) if $\sum {b_n}$ converges, then $\sum {a_n}$ converges

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For any $C > 0$, we may choose an $N$ large enough so that the following holds: 
$$
\sum_{n=N}^\infty  b_n = \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{b_n}{a_n} a_n \geq \sum_{n=N}^\infty C a_n\\
\sum_{n=N}^\infty  a_n = \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{a_n}{b_n} b_n \leq \sum_{n=N}^\infty C b_n
$$
It suffices to consider $C=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\epsilon =1$, for enough great $n $,

$ a_n =b_n \frac {a_n}{b_n}\leq b_n $

finish by comparison criterion.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
There exists $N$ such that if $n>N$, then $a_n<b_n$ by definition of the limit.